# Is Open Data Protocol (odata) Being Widely Embraced by the Development Community?

Tags: api, web-api, standardization

EDIT: In case you aren't familiar with OData, [here you go](https://www.odata.org/).

I am trying to determine whether it is worth learning this technology or if it is something that is not going to catch on.

The premise is interesting, and as a developer of APIs it seems like a good way to offer more flexibility to the developers that consume them.

Unfortunately, I am not seeing much "buzz" regarding Open Data Protocol in the past couple of years so just trying to gauge if it has any chance of being around once I learn it.

Comment: Why the vote to close?  Jeez--is there no where on SE where a developer can ask a general question??

Comment: recommended reading: **[On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)**

Comment: if you have to post a link to it so people know what you're discussing, that suggests its not particularly widespread and in use :-)

Comment: @gnat--I don't get it: this was a question, not a discussion.  How is this legitimate question overwhelming the rest of the site?  Can you recommend a different way to ask it?  Do you see the question as somehow illegitimate?  The link you cited mentions attracting experts--great!  So here is where the experts are, but I can't ask a question unless a very small population of users (like yourself) decide its a question worth asking.  That is very subjective and silly.  I can understand being more strict about this sort of thing on SO, but here I think its you missing the point.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt This is one of those things where you cannot win nor have the ammunition-point-wise to fight. Gain a lot of point on stackoverflow, then you can fight for questions like this not to be closed on this forum. I personally gave up on trying to reason with the gatekeepers.

Comment: This question was legitimate IMO. There is no reason was inevitably going to be mostly "based on opinions" as there is plenty of "fact" available. For example: number of vendors producing OData products, big announcements one way or the other (vendors dropping suport etc), statistics on Google searches, commits/contributors to the odata repo etc etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that:

1. The two "big name" implementors, Netflix and Ebay, [abandoned it a couple of years ago](http://www.ben-morris.com/netflix-has-abandoned-odata-does-the-standard-have-a-future-without-an-ecosystem/) and excitement for OData pretty much died with their departure,
2. [OData is a RESTful way of exposing a query mechanism through an abstraction layer](https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/is-using-odataiqueryable-in-your-web-api-an-inherently-bad-thing/). Such abstractions are now widely seen as leaky abstractions, which are a clear anti-pattern,

I'd suggest OData is slowly dying, if not dead already.

Comment: How is Facebook's new and trendy GraphQL not "exposing a query mechanism through an abstraction layer"?

Comment: Number 2 is vague until useless.

Comment: @DavidArno what's about MS implementation on top of `IQueryable<T>` ? It seems that they are going to add it soon in new ASP.Net Core so I can't say it's really dying.

Comment: _Is slowly dying_: is it? https://www.progress.com/blogs/rest-api-industry-debate-odata-vs-graphql-vs-ords